# irrationality proof taylor series

Tags: calculus

if the taylor series of n-derivable function is
$$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{a_n x^n}{b_n}$$ and If I could show that 
$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to f(c)$$ when $$n\to \infty$$ it is posible afirmate that f(c) is irrational
i try to clarificate a little bit look the following series( it is not  a Laurent series) of the function
$$\frac{\cos (x)}{x+1}$$
$$-\frac{x^6 \cos (1)}{x+1}+\frac{13 x^5}{24}-\frac{13 x^4}{24}+\frac{x^3}{2}-\frac{2 x^3 \cos (1)}{x+1}+\frac{x^2}{2}-x+1$$ the function is infinity derivable and the coefficient taylor series are distint number all rational tend to Cos(1) but never reach the Cos(1) so Cos(1) could not be rational,

Comment: Antonio, what is $c$?  Just some number?

Answer (score 0):

No: if you take any polynomial function that has a zero $c$, the sequence $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ has limit $0=f(c)$ whitch is rational.

Answer (score 0):

Specific counterexample: $a_n=b_n=1$ for all $n$, so that $f(x)=\frac1{1-x}$. Then with $c=0$, we have  $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to f(c)=1$.

Comment: the series of 1/1-x it is posible represent as$$-\frac{x^6}{x-1}+x^5+x^4+\frac{2 x^3}{x-1}+x^3-x^2-x-1$$ this is not use as counterexample cause an==bn are not differents